# Listview adapter does not working because of the fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I think because of the fragments, I need to use getActivity() instead of this. But still it give a fatal error and doesnot work. Please help, thanks in advance...

```
 public class TabFragment2 extends Fragment {


ListView listView;
String[] ids;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {        

 View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag2_layout, container, false);

      _audioModel.LoadModel();
      listView = (ListView)V. findViewById(R.id.lsAudio);
      String[] ids = new String[_audioModel.Audios.size()];
      for (int i= 0; i < ids.length; i++){

          ids[i] = Integer.toString(i+1);
      }

      _audioAdapter adapter = new _audioAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.audio_item, ids);
      listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is a part of my _audioAdapter.java code

```
public class _audioAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Context context;
private final String[] Ids;
private final int rowResourceId;

public _audioAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects) {

    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

    this.context = context;
    this.Ids = objects;
    this.rowResourceId = textViewResourceId;

}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(rowResourceId, parent, false);
    TextView audioName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textAudioName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fight with this problem a lot!!
The problem is on the fragment/activity lifecycle
In the onCreateView if the fragment is the first of your activity the activity does not exist yet...
If you try the debug or post the log cat i think that the error is a NullPointerException on getActivity()

Quick&Dirty trick:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    /* All the code that need getActivity() */
}
```

Comment: Find a simple trick in my edit but this is not a final solution.
With more fragment this can have some problem.
If your activity have only one son fragment this is a fast workaround

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work for me as you said because I have 3 fragments and this fragment is my second one.

Comment: OK try with this, talk about the same problem, the solution is to move all the code related to getActivity() in the onCrate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439392/getting-a-constructor-error-with-arrayadapter-in-a-listfragment-on-android

Comment: I've tried it as well but doesnt work too. I gave up and use tab host. Thank you for your answers