# The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(FragmentActivity, int, int, int, List<String>) is undefined

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter, android-fragmentactivity, android-listfragment

I have used ListFragment in that i have used below code

```
public class TestListFragment extends ListFragment {

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.list_column,
            R.layout.list_column, R.id.text, createDataList(1000));
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

but i am getting stuck where The constructor ArrayAdapter(FragmentActivity, int, int, int, List) is undefined

i have searched it and found [Getting a constructor error with ArrayAdapter in a ListFragment on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439392/getting-a-constructor-error-with-arrayadapter-in-a-listfragment-on-android) same problem in that it is suggesting me that use getActivity() and i have used that but still eclipse don't allow me

Comment: must sure your FragmentActivity imported as a android.support.v4.FragmentActivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no constructor such as

```
ArrayAdapter<String>(FragmentActivity, int, int, int, List<String>)
```

You should instantiate like this :

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.list_column, R.id.text, createDataList(1000));
```

You can check the constructors available at the [official docs site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html).

Comment: @Naveen N, please stop defacing my posts.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Sherlock fragment... then instead of getActivity(), use, getSherlockActivity();